# Temporary materialization on std::initializer_list<T>

Tags: c++, standards

I am reading about Temporarily Materialization, and got stuck on this point:

> Temporary materialization occurs:
>
> - when initializing an object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` from a braced-init-list;

Does this mean that in this case:

```cpp
std::initializer_list<int> x = std::initializer_list<int>{1,3,5};
```

the `initializer_list` is an actual prvalue that is going to be materialized?
If that's the case, does this mean that there's no copy elision going on here, even though after C++17 it should apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it really doesn't matter, because there's no way you could ever observe whether a temporary `std::initializer_list` object is created.

But I think the answer is that the "materialization" described is the materialization of a temporary object with type `int[3]` (array of 3 `int`s) as described in [[dcl.init.list]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#5), to which the `initializer_list` object `x` is bound; it is *not* the materialization of a temporary `initializer_list` object. Copy elision is mandatory in this example.

Comment: Actually, now that you typed this, it makes sense! The materialization happens to T, which is not std::initializer_list<T> itself as I assumed here. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Temporary materialization occurs when initializing an object of type std::initializer_list from a braced-init-list;

That's because the *braced-init-list* is a prvalue.

But you have to know that: An initializer_list is a template class consisting of raw const pointer and size_t variable. **Objects of this class are constructed by automatically allocating a temporary array of type const T[N]**, in which each element of that array is copy-initialized from the corresponding element of the original initializer list, using any necessary non-narrowing implicit conversions. And the original `std::initializer_list` is constructed by calling a somehow constructor passing this temporary array as argument to this constructor. Moreover, **The lifetime of the temporary array is the same as that of the initializer_list object**.

Consider this example:

```
std::initializer_list<const char *> strs{ "AA", "BB" };
```

The braced-init-list `{ "AA", "BB" }` is an prvalue that has to be materialized; therefore the compiler will implicitly create a temporary array, copy-initialize each element from the braced-init-list; and the `strs` object gets constructed to refer to that array. What's really happened implicitly is:

```
const char *tmp[2] = { "AA", "BB" };
std::initializer_list<const char *> strs(tmp, tmp+3)
```

> the initializer_list is an actual prvalue that is going to be materialized?

No, `std::initializer_list` is an template class *type*. Value categories are applied for *expressions*. The prvalue here is the braced-init-list.